# Android-button visibility on VideoView after using videoView.setZOrderOnTop(true);

Tags: android, android-videoview

I have to use `videoView.setZOrderOnTop(true)` compulsorily on android. But after using this I cannot display a button on **videoView**. Is there any way to display a button on **videoView** even after setting `videoView.setZOrderOnTop(true)`?

Comment: @RoberTran I am having same issue. If I use setZOrderOnTop(), then I cannot show any button on VIdeoView and if I remove setZOrderOnTop() then video is not playing, it looks like stable image. Did you fixed this problem?

Comment: @Nitesh Khatri and Robert, have you ever found a working solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
videoView.setZOrderOnTop(true);
videoView.setZOrderMediaOverlay(true);
```

Comment: Thanks. I try but not work. I want show background image and hide background video. I set videoView.setZOrderOnTop(true); is ok, but button play, seekbar ...  cannot display